# Hadoop Example Programs Source Code

Tags: hadoop

I would like to analyze the map and reduce functions for some of the hadoop example programs (such as word count), but I am not sure where the source code is located. I have managed to google the source code for word count, but I believe it should be included somewhere in the hadoop package when I downloaded it.

Does anyone know where I can find the map and reduce functions for the hadoop example programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapper api

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html

The reduce api

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html

A tutorial to get you started

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/mapred_tutorial.html

Comment: Examples are not always packaged with the API in all products; because, occasionally it is nice to use the product without having to drag around a bunch of example code :)